# Error in python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am getting error in the below python code

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
c,d=divmod(len(a),2)
i=iter(a).next 
print ''.join('%s\t%s\n' % (i(),i())
for i in xrange(c))\
+ ('%s\t\n' % (i()) if b==1
    else '')
```

i need to print output is

```
1    2
3    4
5
```

i am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dhsgj.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in xrange(c))\
  File "dhsgj.py", line 5, in <genexpr>
    for i in xrange(c))\
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: what do you expect `i()` to do?

Comment: @user3080953 it calls the `next` function. It's declared in the third line.

Comment: on line 5 you are overwriting `i` from third line

Comment: thank you @AzatIbrakov got it

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to split the array, try to iterate two items at a time.

I've updated your code to make it little bit easier to follow. This should work:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
iterator = iter(a)
for first in iterator:
    try:
        second = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        print first
    else:
        print('%s\t%s\n' % (first, second))
```